# What if the declared variable in for each loop will print outside of the foor loop

Tags: java, foreach

I tried for each loop to find duplicates in an array, if I printing the variable "i" outside of the for each loop, it is providing unexpected output.

Expected: Related errors as like the variable is not declared(as the declared variable is local)

```
package Login;

public class DupsArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 3};
        int length = a.length;
        for (int i : a) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= length - 1; j++) {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) { 
                    System.out.println("Found duplicate" + a[i]);
                    break;
                }

                System.out.print(i);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

11Found duplicate3

Comment: You are not printing `i` outside the enhanced `for` loop... And in that loop, `i` is the current element and not an index.

Comment: For each loops are very useful for cases in which you dont need the index. You are referencing only the value of each element of the array but not the index. Thats why you get unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `i` to iterate the *values* (not indexes) of array `a` and `j` to iterate *indexes*.

Suggestion: instead of using an array you can use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and make you code much simpler:

Iterate the list and for any `item` compare `array.indexOf(item)` with `array.lastIndexOf(item)` - if they're different you found a duplicate!

Comment: Interesting to see this answer having equal amounts of down and upvotes. It is very short, but I cannot see anything wrong with it. Maybe point out more clearly that `i` is not an index but an element and `j` is an index. (didn't vote at all on this answer so far).

Comment: @deHaar thanks I appreciate the feedback, tried to clarify it a bit.

Comment: I am still a bit confused that where the value "11" comes from? the detail in further I the value "11" neither based a value or index.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it without an enhanced `for`-loop, because index comparison is needed to avoid false positives, e.g. you compare element `i == 3` to element `a[j] == 3`, which might be the same, but how do you want to determine that?
To get around it, you would need an `indexOf`, so it would boil down to index comparison again.

I would use two classic `for`-loops and compare the indexes, skipping equal ones:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // the source to be investigated
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 3};
    // a container for duplicates found
    Set<Integer> dups = new HashSet<>();

    // iterate your elements of the source array
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // compare each one to the others
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            // find out if the elements are equal
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                // if they are, add it to the set of duplicates
                dups.add(a[i]);
                // as an alternative, you could print them here, too
                // System.out.println("Duplicate found: " + a[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // print the duplicates found
    System.out.println("Duplicates found: ");
    dups.forEach(d -> System.out.println(d));
}
```

> Please read the code comments and note that you don't have to store the duplicates in case you just want to print them. Storing is needed for further processing or printing it some time later, maybe on demand.

Comment: if you'll change the inner loop to start from `i+1` you'll iterate half the items you're doing now and you can also get rid of the check `if (i != j)`. Second, you can save the dups in a Set and avoid the check if it's not already there.

Comment: @alfasin Thanks, I have optimized the solution according to your suggestions.